# What's the difference between MinGW, GNU and Cywin makefiles?

Tags: makefile, cygwin, mingw

Are there any? I'd like to have one makefile handle all the build targets across platforms.

Comment: Alternatively, could I use MSVC with MinGW makefiles?

Answer (score 0):

MinGW and GNU are the same.  Both use GNU Make (go figure!).  There are options for Cygwin, including GNU make, cmake and possibly others.  If you go with the same make, then you have a starting point for portable Makefiles.  However ...

- Makefile recipes often include OS-specific commands as each line in a recipe is handed off to the OS command shell for execution.
- The tools available under a specific OS may vary.
- Paths are always a bit of a challenge.

Cygwin and MinGW each provide environments that attempt to mimic UNIX and make the issues above easier to deal with.